# Looping through Photoshop layers in Javascript

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I'm trying to write a Photoshop script that will show all layers of a given name.  I need to loop through all the possible nested layer sets and am using the following code:

```
function showBounds(layerNode)
{
    for(var layer in layerNode.artLayers)
    {
        if (layer.name == "@bounds")
        {
            layer.visible = 1;
        }
    }

    showBounds(layerNode.layerSets);
}

showBounds(app.activeDocument.doc.layerSets);
```

But when I run it, I get the following error:

```
Error 1302: No such element
Line: 5
->      for(var layer in layerNode.artLayers)
```

artLayers should be a property of LayerSets, so I'm confused.

This is also my first attempt at scripting PS (and using javascript), so there might be some fundamental concept I am not getting.

Comment: You don't need the `var` in the `for(..in..)` statement

Comment: It looks to me like some `layerNode` doesn't have a `layerNode.artLayers`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need something more like:

```
function showBounds(layerNode) {    
    for (var i=0; i<layerNode.length; i++) {

        showBounds(layerNode[i].layerSets);

        for(var layerIndex=0; layerIndex < layerNode[i].artLayers.length; layerIndex++) {
            var layer=layerNode[i].artLayers[layerIndex];
            if (layer.name == "@bounds") {
                layer.visible = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

showBounds(app.activeDocument.layerSets);
```

Also, javascripts for...in syntax doesn't work the way you think it does. It's not like a foreach loop. It loops over the property names of an object.

Comment: This worked (thanks!)...but oh my god is PS scripting slow. Running this on file with 20 layers took 30 seconds.  There is just no excuse for that in a $600 program. Googling shows nothing but complaints about how slow PS scripting is.  Oh well...I tried.  :-)

Comment: Hmm...I tried it on a 2000x2000 file with 36 layers that were all in one layerset and it only took about 2 seconds. This was with CS6.

Comment: I'm on CS6 as well. One outer layer set containing 20 layer sets that each had 4 or 5 art layers.  I'm running on an iMac (8 cores).  When I ran the script, the PS screen flickered like it was trying to do an update after each command.

Comment: Well, if you had 20 layer sets and each had 4 or 5 layers, then that's more then 20 layers :). That's 80-100. :) Still, it seems like looping through layers to get layer names should be WAAAAY faster.